# SSH keys not working

Tags: ssh

I'm using `ssh-keygen` to generate a key on Ubuntu 10.10, then using `ssh-copy-id` to copy the key to two remote machines that are running 10.04 (one desktop, the other server).

But here's the thing: I can SSH into the desktop without a password, but then some time later I'm asked for a password again. The server always asks for a password and never lets me login with my key.

I've checked permissions on the `.ssh` folder, the `authorized_keys file`, my `id_dsa` and my `id_dsa.pub` on all hosts, and they're inline with what the [Ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.10/serverguide/C/openssh-server.html) suggests. I've even copied my keys using `scp` and *gasp* set permissions to files and folders to 777 just to rule out any permission issues.

Does anyone have a foolproof way of setting up SSH keys on Ubuntu for password-less SSH access before I change profession and become a flower arranger?

Comment: +1 for the question, as well as that last line.

Comment: You might have a permission issue still; Your keys will not work unless they are readable by the owner only. Giving them weaker permissions only ensures that they will not work.

Comment: Tried that. As I said, I changed permissions to what the guide said and then tried 777. Still doesn't explain why it works for a while, then stops...

Comment: Have you tried running `tail -f /var/log/auth.log` on the server while you log in to see if sshd logs any helpful information?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, I suggest, if you can, to remove+purge, then reinstall openssh-client/server on the three machines, and remove each ~/.ssh, so that you start from a clean situation.

Next, follow this [ubuntu wiki page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys) that treats more specifically of ssh keys configuration.

Last, keep in mind the following issue: from [debian ssh wiki](http://wiki.debian.org/ssh#ssh_without_password):

> Login without password does not work
>   if group or world has write
>   permissions for the home directory on
>   the remote machine.

Comment: It was a permissions thing. Bad ass, thanks bud.

Answer (score 1):

The operation of ssh is governed by a twisty maze of a couple dozen configuration files spread across `~/.ssh` and `/etc/ssh` on both the client and server machines all different.

And the Pluggable Authentication Module (`man 7 PAM`) joins in the party for extra kicks.

I will give a nickel to anyone who can explain the precise semantics of all these interacting mechanisms as I've never bothered to spend a day figuring them out.

Comment: So here's the thing: I need password-less access for a bit of software I'm using. If a login attempt is followed by a password prompt, the software breaks. I have no way to change this mechanism, so using SSH keys is a must. Or I'm going to start looking at petunias.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the permissions of my home folder, changing the permissions for the ~/.ssh folder solved my problem according to [this](https://superuser.com/a/215506/133098).

Answer (score 0):

http://linuxproblem.org/art_9.html

Following is what worked for me on 16.04

> Your aim
>
> You want to use Linux and OpenSSH to automate your tasks. Therefore
>   you need an automatic login from host A / user a to Host B / user b.
>   You don't want to enter any passwords, because you want to call ssh
>   from a within a shell script.
>
> How to do it
>
> First log in on A as user a and generate a pair of authentication
>   keys. Do not enter a passphrase:
>
> a@A:~> ssh-keygen -t rsa Generating public/private rsa key pair. Enter
>   file in which to save the key (/home/a/.ssh/id_rsa):  Created
>   directory '/home/a/.ssh'. Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
>   Enter same passphrase again:  Your identification has been saved in
>   /home/a/.ssh/id_rsa. Your public key has been saved in
>   /home/a/.ssh/id_rsa.pub. The key fingerprint is:
>   3e:4f:05:79:3a:9f:96:7c:3b:ad:e9:58:37:bc:37:e4 a@A Now use ssh to
>   create a directory ~/.ssh as user b on B. (The directory may already
>   exist, which is fine):
>
> a@A:~> ssh b@B mkdir -p .ssh b@B's password:  Finally append a's new
>   public key to b@B:.ssh/authorized_keys and enter b's password one last
>   time:
>
> a@A:~> cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh b@B 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys'
>   b@B's password:  From now on you can log into B as b from A as a
>   without password:
>
> a@A:~> ssh b@B A note from one of our readers: Depending on your
>   version of SSH you might also have to do the following changes:
>
> Put the public key in .ssh/authorized_keys2 Change the permissions of
>   .ssh to 700 Change the permissions of .ssh/authorized_keys2 to 640